# Passing an element to a lambda by reference-to-const

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, lambda, decltype

Inside an algorithm, I want to create a lambda that accepts an element by reference-to-const:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void solve_world_hunger(Iterator it)
{
    auto lambda = [](const decltype(*it)& x){
        auto y = x;   // this should work
        x = x;        // this should fail
    };
}
```

The compiler does not like this code:

> Error: »const«-qualifier cannot be applied to »int&« (translated manually from German)

Then I realized that `decltype(*it)` is already a reference, and of course those cannot be made `const`. If I remove the `const`, the code compiles, but I want `x = x` to fail.

Let us trust the programmer (which is me) for a minute and get rid of the `const` and the explicit `&`, which gets  dropped due to reference collapsing rules, anyways.  But wait, is `decltype(*it)` actually **guaranteed** to be a reference, or should I add the explicit `&` to be on the safe side?

If we do not trust the programmer, I can think two solutions to solve the problem:

```
(const typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*it)>::type& x)

(const typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type& x)
```

You can decide for yourself which one is uglier. Ideally, I would want a solution that does not involve any template meta-programming, because my target audience has never heard of that before. So:

Question 1: Is `decltype(*it)&` always the same as `decltype(*it)`?

Question 2: How can I pass an element by reference-to-const without template meta-programming?

Comment: An english error would be nice! :)

Comment: @Pubby I tried my best, feel free to correct :)

Comment: @sehe the question is not about top-level const.

Comment: -1, wrong semantics in code.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes ... my bad. removing

Comment: @KonradRudolph Where? What's wrong?

Comment: @BЈовић Isn’t obvious? The function is supposed to solve world hunger but it doesn’t fulfil its contract.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: if the darn thing compiled then maybe it would, the meaning of ill-formed programs is implementation-defined ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Well, neither of Fred’s suggested fixed would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1: no, the requirement on InputIterator is merely that `*it` is convertible to T (table 72, in "Iterator requirements").

So `decltype(*it)` could for example be `const char&` for an iterator whose `value_type` is `int`. Or it could be `int`. Or `double`.

Using `iterator_traits` is not equivalent to using `decltype`, decide which you want.

For the same reason, `auto value = *it;` does *not* necessarily give you a variable with the value type of the iterator.

Question 2: might depend what you mean by template meta-programming.

If using a traits type is TMP, then there's no way of specifying "const reference to the value type of an iterator" without TMP, because `iterator_traits` is the only means to access the value type of an arbitrary iterator.

If you want to const-ify the `decltype` then how about this?

```
template<typename Iterator>
void solve_world_hunger(Iterator it)
{
    const auto ret_type = *it;
    auto lambda = [](decltype(ret_type)& x){
        auto y = x;   // this should work
        x = x;        // this should fail
    };
}
```

You might have to capture `ret_type` in order to use its type, I can't easily check at the moment.

Unfortunately it dereferences the iterator an extra time. You could probably write some clever code to avoid that, but the clever code would end up being an alternative version of `remove_reference`, hence TMP.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite the bullet and explain `iterator_traits` then.

Comment: @FredOverflow: writing a book/tutorial?

Comment: Nope. If I wrote a book, I'm sure the Lounge would be the first to know ;)